# File system encryption for IOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, filesystems, data-protection, macfuse

I know on Mac OS,we can use Macfuse for write a file system in user space,we can create a box encryption.
I don't know on IOS has a framework,library like FUSE,Macfuse that i can write my file system for encryption/decryption file (possible mount on a directory/folder).
Can anyone point me a solution?

Comment: iOS (maybe new with 5.x) has a facility for semi-automatically encrypting stored files.  I don't know anything about it, though.

Comment: [Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW11) is an intro about ios file protection.

Answer (score 10):

As for built-in iOS support, there are a number of options, varying from a per-file basis to encrypting the entire sandbox of your app. I suggest you read [Protecting Data Using On-Disk Encryption](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StrategiesforImplementingYourApp/StrategiesforImplementingYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW21) in the iOS App Programming Guide.

All of these options, however, require the user to have a passcode set on the device. Older devices may not support file system encryption.

One of the options not mentioned in this documentation is to set the `DataProtectionClass` entitlement value to `NSFileProtectionComplete`. This will automatically protect all the files in your app's sandbox.

Finally, I suggest you watch the WWDC 2011 Video [Securing iOS Applications](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=208) ("Securing Application Data" on Apple's video page) and hear directly from Apple engineers about the best practices. This video covers pretty much everything that Apple offers.

edit:

According to people on the dev forums, the DataProtectionClass entitlement may not be working correctly in current iOS versions.

Comment: I want to write a file system to reading/writing encrypted file.So i want user don't aware and get encrypted file.So i think NSFileProtection cannot apply in this case.Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You can set the [`NSFileProtection`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsfilemanager_Class/Reference/Reference.html) attribute on a file to have it encrypted using a key derived from the user's passcode.